# How to print critical CSS into index.html using Webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm working on a large single-page application, with very large CSS & JS files that are generated by Webpack, which causes a [flash of unstyled content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) when the app is initially loaded.

To avoid that, I would like to print the critical part of the CSS into the head of the document, so that the document will not appear unstyled while the browser is processing the rest of the JS & CSS.

This CSS is written in SASS, and is dependant on global app variables, so webpack must process the files to compile them from SASS to CSS before printing it to the document head.

How can this be done with Webpack?

Answer (score 2):

The way I did it is

1. Separate critical CSS into its own asset with [separate loader rule and ExtractTextPlugin instance](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/#multiple-instances);
2. Disable default inject of `html-webpack-plugin` to inject assets manually in the template;
3. Non-critical assets are injected via links to files ([example](https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/blob/master/index.ejs)). Critical CSS is injected inline using `compilation` variable ([example](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/examples/inline/template.jade)).

*Note*. You can put the logic in a function in `HtmlWebpackPlugin` options. Example is at the end of the answer.

This way, one has pretty much full control of how the assets are included, as in tags, attributes, positions.

There are several plugins that might also help with inlining CSS and JS, such as

- [html-webpack-inline-source-plugin](https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin)
- [style-ext-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/style-ext-html-webpack-plugin)
- [script-ext-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin)

but they take away the flexibility of having full control over format, logic, and output, and substitute it with limited config options.

---

Example config

```js
plugins: [
    //...

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'path-to-index-template',
        inject: false,

        injectCriticalCss(htmlWebpackPluginStats, compilation) {
            return lodash(htmlWebpackPluginStats.files.chunks)
                .map(chunk => chunk.css)
                .flatten()
                .filter(cssFilename => /^critical\b/.test(cssFilename))
                .map(cssFilename => `<style>${
                    compilation.assets[cssFilename].source()
                }</style>`)
                .join('\n');
        },

        injectNonCriticalCss(htmlWebpackPluginStats) {
            return lodash(htmlWebpackPluginStats.files.chunks)
                .map(chunk => chunk.css)
                .flatten()
                .filter(cssFilename => !/^critical\b/.test(cssFilename))
                .map(cssFilename => `<link rel="preload" as="style" href="${
                    cssFilename
                }" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"/>`)
                .join('\n');
        },

        //...
    }),

    //...
]
```

and then in the template

```html
<html>
<head>

    <!-- ... -->

    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.injectCriticalCss(htmlWebpackPlugin, compilation) %>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- ... -->

    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.injectNonCriticalCss(htmlWebpackPlugin) %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good answer, thanks. But how do you generating critical css itself? I'm using `html-critical-webpack-plugin ` and seems it can generate critical css only after `HtmlWebpackPlugin` finished it's job.

Comment: @MyTitle, in my case, the critical styles are static and known (well, they are limited to the file `critical.styl`). So I have a rule `{ test: /^critical\.styl$/, use: extractCriticalStylesPlugin.extract(...) }` where `extractCriticalStylesPlugin` is an instance of `ExtractTextPlugin` for generating a separate css-asset for critical css. And as shown above, that asset gets injected with `injectCriticalCss` into index.html within a `style` tag. I don't think I can help with setting it up with `html-critical-webpack-plugin` though.

Answer (score 1):

You need use [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) in order to extract it from js file and write to a single file so that you can link it to head of html.

See how it is used with [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader).

```
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].css',
})

module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: extractSass.extract({
          use: [{
            loader: 'css-loader', options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true
            }
          }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader', options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true
            }
          }],
          // use style-loader in development
          fallback: 'style-loader'
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractSass,
  ]
```

Comment: But how can it be used for only part of the CSS? And also, this will load the CSS as an external source, and I want it to be printed to the HEAD

Comment: Every css and scss import in your js file will be comipled into css file you mentioned to ExtractTextPlugin. For example. all your imported css or scss file used for entry.js file will be written to the css file you specify to ExtractTextPlugin. Please give it a try I am sure it will work.

Comment: OK, so that will allow me to generate part of the CSS, but it will still load it as an external resource. How do I print it to the HEAD so that it is available immediately?

Comment: May be this would be helpful. https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin. Instead of creating a js bundle u can generate a html file. Also keeping css in head will prevent unstyled flash.